# How to create a new background process in a KSH "while read" loop?

Tags: linux, ksh

The following test script has a problem. When I add the line `(sleep 5 ) &` in the script then the "while read" loop does not read all lines from the file, but only prints the first line.

But when I remove the `( sleep 5 ) &` from the script, then the script prints all lines as defined in the file.

Why the `( sleep 5 ) &` causes this?

And how to solve the problem? I want to create a new process (for which the `sleep` is just an example) in the while loop:

```
$ more test 
#!/bin/ksh  
while read -r line ; do
    echo Read a line:
    echo $line

    ( sleep 5 )&
    RESULT=$!
    echo Started background sleep with process id $RESULT

    sleep 1
    echo Slept for a second

    kill $RESULT 
    echo Killed background sleep with process id $RESULT
done < file
echo Completed
```

On my Linux, when using the following contents of `file`:

```
$ more file 
123 aaa 
234 bbb 
556 ccc
```

...running `./test` just gives me:

```
Read a line:
123 aaa
Started background sleep with process id 4181
Slept for a second 
Killed background sleep with process id 4181
Completed
```

Comment: This question is probably better suited on Stack Overflow. Your question will be migrated there automatically.

Comment: You've been asked several time to properly format your posts. Use the `101010` button or indent each line of code four spaces, please. Also, you need to mark some answers as accepted.

Comment: It works just fine for me.

Comment: I just rolled back your editing again Yael, don't rollback edits made by others if it improves formatting. It's considered rude, stubborn and childish. If you don't like people editing your posts, this site may not be for you.

Comment: Dennis did you check it

Comment: Dennis did you check the script?

Comment: Dennis probably used the script as it is now in your post, I suggest you try that.

Comment: hi again
this script as I edit on the first time is the same as it is now
and the problem still exist
yael

Comment: As for "when I remove the `( sleep 5 ) &` from the script", I assume you're also removing the "kill" then?

Comment: No the (sleep 5)& must be in the script
the problem is why the loop not cont if I put the (sleep 5)& ??
yael

Comment: The script above works fine for me (on a Mac), and for Dennis. Assuming this is just an example version of something more useful, did you indeed run the exact same script yourself?

Comment: And as for "why the loop not cont" -- of course the loop *does* sleep for a second, due to the "sleep 1". But after that it continues fine, on my computer.

Comment: yes
when I run this script , the script print only the first line:
123 aaa

the target is to print all lines in file
yael

Comment: did you machine work on LINUX?

Comment: Does *yours*? You're not giving us that information... :-( (Like I wrote: I tested on a Mac, which has KSH built-in as well.)

Comment: my machine is LINUX
yael

Comment: I started a Ubuntu 9.10 machine, but that does not have KSH installed. Using the default Bash shell gives me no problems on that Ubuntu machine either. Odd.

Comment: according to your last test runing
I and you have the same results

Comment: I tested it on Ubuntu 9.10 with ksh 93 and it works fine. I even changed the data file to have DOS line endings using `unix2dos` to see if something like that might be your problem. It still worked fine (both versions of your script). By the way, the subshell around `sleep 5` is unnecessary, but I doubt that it's the cause of your problem. You can just do `sleep 5&`

Comment: @yeal, *according to your last test runing I and you have the same results* -- no, I get *all* lines (just like Dennis does). I copied *your* results into your question, not mine of course. Please edit the question to also include the version of the script that prints all lines for you too. (So: the version without the "(sleep 5)&" and whatever else you removed then.)

Comment: (And see [How do comment replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work))

Comment: ( sleep 5 ) &  because its only exampe
the orig script its difent like: ( sleep 20 ; sed ........ ; ... ) &

Comment: so finaly we not have solution -(:

Comment: 1) What does `ksh -m ./test` give you? 2) I doubt it helps, but try `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/ksh` 3) Run `ksh -v ./test` to see if that gives you more details? 4) What version of KSH are you using? See `ksh 'print ${.sh.version}'` 5) What Linux are you using? See `uname -v` 6) As this whole post is quite confusing, again: please show us the stripped version of the script that *does* work for you? (So, like I asked two times earlier: the version without the `(sleep 5)&`.)

Answer (score 1):

From the Ksh changelog for ksh93s:

> 06-10-23  A bug in which the value of `$!` was affected by a background job started from a subshell has been fixed.

If your version of ksh is older than that (you should mention the version in your question!), you might be observing this bug.